# Comparing cardinal_number fields in Postgres/Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, ansi-sql

I'm trying to return, from `information_schema.columns` all the columns in a table except for the final column (i.e. `ordinal_position` less than a given value), but whenever I try to use the less than operator to compare cardinal_number datatypes, I get an error like `value for domain information_schema.cardinal_number violates check constraint "cardinal_number_domain_check"`.

I've tried casting and re-casting, but I'm stuck.  Nothing I've tried works.  I can't even do ordinal_position < 10, using a hard-coded value.

Any help us appreciated....

UPDATE: I found a work around that doesn't use the < operator...

```
  AND ordinal_position NOT IN (
  SELECT MAX(ordinal_position)
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
    AND table_name   = 'my_table'
  )
```

It's still curious that it doesn't let me use the < operator with the cardinal_number data type.

Comment: Please show us your current code.